# What happened to HornGet?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration

What happened to Hornget? The HornGet Project used to run a CI build server for a lot of major open source .NET projects, such as NHibernate. It seems to have disappeared and the domain is squatted.

Is the service running elsewhere?

Note: This question isn't specifically about the HornGet package manager. Several other (better) alternatives exist. This is about the community CI server.

Comment: HornGet, the package manager, hasn't has much development on it in a while. I would suppose that's due to NuGet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hornget was closed down.

I could not get the community buy in that was needed.  I think having a CI server that merged all the major .NET OSS build projects would have been of great use but everybody is busy and on limited time.  Such is life.

There are now many package managers that do a better job.

I personally use Openwrap over nuget.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I have never heard about HornGet before, but your question got me curious. I hope there is only one project by that name, but having that said, it looks as if it is indeed no longer actively developed: http://thesoftwaresimpleton.blogspot.com/2010/04/invention-is-not-invented-here.html:

> ...
>   I know about failure on this front
>   more than most as in a lot of ways
>   *horn [http://www.hornget.net/] has been a failure*.  It is
>   certainly a failure in the community I
>   tried to build around it and it still
>   has some failings in the technical
>   solution.  I can though say I tried. 
>   ...
>   (emphasis added)

The latest sources seem to be on [GitHub](https://github.com/dagda1/horn_src).

Looks like the web site itself (and thus possibly the CI server) was never really [restored](http://groups.google.com/group/horn-development/browse_thread/thread/a149420724eee86a/995a645c06adc328?lnk=raot), well at least not for something other then blue pills ;-) (which is not to imply that this was done by the original author(s) of HornGet, of course).